# R install package stringi in renv

Tags: r, stringr, stringi, renv

I am trying to install the package stringi with `renv::install()`.

Normally, I would use

```
install.packages('stringi', configure.vars='ICUDT_DIR=path/to/icudt61l.zip/')
```

To specify the location of icudt61l.zip dependency.
How can I do this in renv ?

I tried to add `ICUDT_DIR='path/to/icudt61l.zip/'` in my .Rprofile but it didn't work.

Any idea how to tell renv where is ICU to install stringi ?

Here is the error I get

```
> renv::install("stringi")
...
Installing stringi [1.6.2] ...
    FAILED
Error installing package 'stringi':
===================================
...
** package ‘stringi’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
checking for R_HOME... /opt/R/4.0.3/lib/R
checking for R... /opt/R/4.0.3/lib/R/bin/R
...
checking with pkg-config for the system ICU4C... 50.1.2
checking for ICU4C >= 55... no
*** ICU4C 50.1.2 has been detected
*** Minimal requirements, i.e., ICU4C >= 55, are not met
*** Trying with 'standard' fallback flags
checking whether an ICU4C-based project can be built... yes
checking programmatically for sufficient U_ICU_VERSION_MAJOR_NUM... no
*** This version of ICU4C cannot be used.
*** Using the ICU 69 bundle.
checking whether we may compile src/icu69/common/putil.cpp... yes
checking whether we may compile src/icu69/i18n/number_affixutils.cpp... yes
checking whether alignof(std::max_align_t) is available... no
checking whether alignof(::max_align_t) is available... yes
checking whether the ICU data library can be downloaded... downloading the ICU data library (icudt)
output path: icu69/data/icu4c-69_1-data-bin-l.zip
trying URL 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gagolews/stringi/master/src/icu69/data/icu4c-69_1-data-bin-l.zip'
Error in download.file(paste(href, fname, sep = ""), icudtzipfname, mode = "wb"): cannot open URL 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gagolews/stringi/master/src/icu69/data/icu4c-69_1-data-bin-l.zip'

trying URL 'http://raw.githubusercontent.com/gagolews/stringi/master/src/icu69/data/icu4c-69_1-data-bin-l.zip'
Error in download.file(paste(href, fname, sep = ""), icudtzipfname, mode = "wb"): cannot open URL 'http://raw.githubusercontent.com/gagolews/stringi/master/src/icu69/data/icu4c-69_1-data-bin-l.zip'

icudt download failed
Error: Stopping on error
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In download.file(paste(href, fname, sep = ""), icudtzipfname, mode = "wb") :
  URL 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gagolews/stringi/master/src/icu69/data/icu4c-69_1-data-bin-l.zip': status was 'Couldn't connect to server'
2: In download.file(paste(href, fname, sep = ""), icudtzipfname, mode = "wb") :
  URL 'http://raw.githubusercontent.com/gagolews/stringi/master/src/icu69/data/icu4c-69_1-data-bin-l.zip': status was 'Couldn't connect to server'
Execution halted
*** *********************************************************************
*** stringi cannot be built.
*** Failed to download the ICU data library (icudt). Stopping now.
*** For build environments that have no internet access,
*** see the INSTALL file for a workaround.
*** *********************************************************************
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘stringi’
* removing ‘/var/projects/iml/GDCFA21N/avertie_test/renv/staging/2/stringi’
Error: install of package 'stringi' failed [error code 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `?renv::install`:

```
Package Configuration:

     Many R packages have a 'configure' script that needs to be run to
     prepare the package for installation. Arguments and environment
     variables can be passed through to those scripts in a manner
     similar to install.packages. In particular, the R options
     'configure.args' and 'configure.vars' can be used to map package
     names to their appropriate configuration. For example:

     # installation of RNetCDF may require us to set include paths for netcdf
     configure.args = c(RNetCDF = "--with-netcdf-include=/usr/include/udunits2"))
     options(configure.args = configure.args)
     renv::install("RNetCDF")

     Similarly, additional flags that should be passed to R CMD INSTALL
     can be set via the 'install.opts' R option:

     # installation of R packages using the Windows Subsystem for Linux
     # may require the `--no-lock` flag to be set during install
     options(install.opts = "--no-lock")
     renv::install("xml2")
```

Setting something like:

```
options(configure.vars = list(stringi = "ICUDT_DIR=path/to/icudt61l.zip"))
```

should hopefully get you unstuck.

Answer (score 3):

```
install.packages("stringi", configure.vars="ICUDT_DIR=<icudt_dir>")
```

just use this command, can be load ICUDT from local.
if you run this all have ERROR,in icudt cannot connect.You should follow this  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gagolews/stringi/master/INSTALL.

#### follow like this:

## ICU Data Library and No Internet Access

Note that if you choose to use our ICU4C bundle, then -- by default -- the
ICU data library will be downloaded from one of our mirror servers.
However, if you have already downloaded a version of `icudt*.zip` suitable
for your platform (big/little endian), you may wish to install the
package by calling:

```r
install.packages("stringi", configure.vars="ICUDT_DIR=<icudt_dir>")
```

Moreover, if you have **no internet access** on the machines
you try to install stringi on, try fetching the latest development version
of the package, as it is shipped with the `ICU` data archives.
You can build a distributable source package that includes all the required
ICU data files (for off-line use) by omitting some relevant lines in
the `.Rbuildignore` file. The following command sequence should do the trick:

```sh
wget https://github.com/gagolews/stringi/archive/master.zip -O stringi.zip
unzip stringi.zip
sed -i '/\/icu..\/data/d' stringi-master/.Rbuildignore
R CMD build stringi-master
```

Assuming the most recent development version of the package is numbered x.y.z,
a file named `stringi_x.y.z.tar.gz` is created in the current working directory.
The package can now be installed (the source bundle may be propagated via
`scp` etc.) by executing:

```sh
R CMD INSTALL stringi_x.y.z.tar.gz
```

Alternatively, call from within an R session:

```r
install.packages("stringi_x.y.z.tar.gz", repos=NULL)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I think the final diagnostic, `perhaps you're not connected to the internet` wasn't applicable in the OP's case, but your suggestion of get `stringi` development version from somewhere might not solve such connectivity issues either. The bulk of your suggestions, except the final instruction, frustratingly point to being connected. Would you be satisfied with that advise were you in the OP's seat?